# data driven unit test url with &

Tags: xml

in Order.xml

```
<order>
  <url>"http://order.aspx?id=1&amp;name=abc"</url>
</order>
```

in test method

```
[TestMethod]
public void OrderDocUrlTest()
{
    orderXml = XElement.Load("order.xml");
    var expected = orderXml.Elements("url").Value;

    var actual = client.GetOrderDocUrl(); 
    //actual = "http://order.aspx?id=1&name=abc"

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual)
   //will fail because "&amp" and "&" are not same
}
```

Question is how to let this unit test pass without replace "&" to "&" in code. Anyway, I just found I have to replace "&" to "&" before comparing expected and actual values.

Comment: This question is hard to interpret.  I suggest expanding if possible to help people try to understand what is being asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use XElement.Load("Order.xml") will replace "&" to "&"!. My bad.